# Reproduce Google Heart with iOS7 MapKit's custom tiles

Tags: ios, 3d, mapkit

I would love to reproduce GoogleHeart-like 3D map flyover even when offline.

As of iOS 7 MapKit allows us to draw custom offline tiles. It also allows us to set a Camera in order to see the map in 3D or 2.5D as you may wish to call it.

I was wondering: can I draw a 3D shape like Apple does for its flyover feature, on my custom tiles?

I need to apply a "bump-map" to the map in order to get a GoogleHeart-like 3D view and I was wondering if Apple would allow me to do just that with iOS 7 and custom tiles rendering + camera settings.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have experimented pretty extensively with this, but there is no supported way to do this. Right now, Apple only offers raster tile-based overlay, albeit with automatic 2.5/3D transformation when overlaid on a map. Hopefully in the future they will support 3D API and/or custom, say, OpenGL-based augmentation to the map.

Comment: Thanks for the precious answer! Would you be able to advice me a viable solution? Should I use OpenGL ES directly and forget about MapKit altogether or what?